# Error using List Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm receiving a "can't find symbol" error when trying to run this code. It's in regard to the List line of code. It is throwing it on the List and ArrayList. I can't figure how this is implemented wrong. The script calls a class called Employee. The List is to contain all objects created from Employee. Then should be able to print the List.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class PayrollProgram
{


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    while (!emp.name.equals("STOP"))
    {
    Employee emp = new Employee();

    System.out.print("Employee's Name: ");
    emp.name = scan.next();

    if(emp.name.equals("STOP"))
        {
            System.out.printf("The Application is STOPPING......");
        break;
        }

    System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $ ");
    emp.wage = scan.nextDouble();
    while (emp.wage < 0) 
    {
        System.out.printf("Please Enter a Positive Number! \n");
        System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $ ");  
        emp.wage = scan.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.print("Hours Worked in Week: ");
    emp.hours = scan.nextDouble();
    while (emp.hours < 0) 
    {
        System.out.printf("Please Enter a Positive Number! \n");
        System.out.print("Hours Worked in Week: ");
        emp.hours = scan.nextDouble();
    }

    employees.add(emp);
    emp.printEmployee();

    }
    for(Employee emp : employees)
        {
        System.out.println(emp.name);
        }
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've imported neither `java.util.List` nor `java.util.ArrayList`.  You should do that.

You also need to import your `Employee` class, if you've defined that in a separate package.

Comment: Thanks that fixed one problem. Now I'm recieving an error on the for loop saying the variable emp is already defined in the main method. If I take out the Employee declatation for emp, I receive errors saying "not a statement", "; excepted", ": illegal start of statement"

Comment: @AwayFromMyDesk, change this: `while (!emp.name.equals("STOP"))` to this: `while (true)`.

Answer (score 1):

YOU should import correct packages & also you should create the Object of employee before while loop

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
while (!emp.name.equals("STOP"))
{

System.out.print("Employee's Name: ");
emp.name = scan.next();

if(emp.name.equals("STOP"))
    {
        System.out.printf("The Application is STOPPING......");
    break;
    }

System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $ ");
emp.wage = scan.nextDouble();
while (emp.wage < 0) 
{
    System.out.printf("Please Enter a Positive Number! \n");
    System.out.print("Enter hourly wage: $ ");  
    emp.wage = scan.nextDouble();
}

System.out.print("Hours Worked in Week: ");
emp.hours = scan.nextDouble();
while (emp.hours < 0) 
{
    System.out.printf("Please Enter a Positive Number! \n");
    System.out.print("Hours Worked in Week: ");
    emp.hours = scan.nextDouble();
}

employees.add(emp);
emp.printEmployee();

}
```